# Gazebo Physics Solver Type: quick vs. world

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Can anyone expand upon the quantitative/qualitative differences between running with the "quick" or "world" solver settings in Gazebo?

My understand is the quick solver is faster than world, but at what expense? Is one or the other quantitatively more accurate?

Is the world solver currently supported? In the latest DRCsim release changing the solver type to "world" makes the sim fail.

Many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/232/gazebo-physics-solver-type:-quick-vs.-world/) by [RoboUser](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/88/robouser/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi RoboUser,

When you use "world" you are using a method that takes more time in computation and memory. Conversely, using "quick" is faster and uses less memory.

However, "world" is more accurate than "quick". If you are simulating a big system using "world" it could take much more time and use a lot of resources of your computer. (maybe this was the cause of the crash simulating the DRC)

Btw,
You can have more information about the ODE solver in the [ODE page](http://www.ode.org/).

---

Originally posted by [vcparedesc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/183/vcparedesc/) with karma: 43 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0